# How to make a console app read different lines from a text file?

Tags: vb.net

So I was just playing around with VB console apps and was wondering how to read a single text file but read the separate lines. In my example, I'm playing around with a credential storage containing fake data as in the form of a username and password. I'm not worried about encrypting anything as of yet but as my question states, how to make the app read line 1 for username for site a, line 2 as password for site a etc. Sorry if I'm not too clear, I can elaborate further if need be.

Comment: Have you tried something? What code you have already written that doesn't work? Have you done some research on File IO operations in VB.NET?

Comment: @Steve I have used the My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\pass.txt") and thats all I really know of reading files. I have tried doing some research into it but nothing seemed to really meet what I need. The only other option I can think of is used seperate text files.

Comment: That would be a bad design. Consider an XML or an INI file instead. If you do, there are standard ways of reading and writing them. Regarding plain text read, try [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) instead.

Comment: There any reason you can't store these as keys in an app.config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well supposing that your text file is composed by repeating lines where the odd ones are the usernames and the even ones are the passwords then

```
Dim lines() as String = File.ReadAllLines("FileName.txt")

if (lines.Length MOD 2) <> 0 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Lines not even")
Else

    For i = 0 to lines.Length - 1 Step 2
        Console.WriteLine("User={0} with password={1}", lines(i), lines(i+1))
    Next
End If
```

This works only if the number of lines in the files is exactly even

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains alternating lines of username and password, then this should do:

```
Using file As FileStream = New FileStream(path, ...other constructor options...)
  Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(file)
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
      username = reader.ReadLine
      password = reader.ReadLine
    End While
  End Using
End Using
```

Of course everything must line up perfectly for this to work - and nothing is ever that perfect.